# Are there any methods to exponentiate a real number with a number from an arbitrary field?

Tags: field-theory, exponentiation, quaternions

How can I take the following exponent, for some real-valued number a?
$$a^{3+2j-9k+3i}$$
over the field of quaternions, or any field for that matter? On wikipedia we are given the following formula,

[image]

which seems relatively straight forward, but I do not know how to find a numerical expansion for any real-number a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming that $a>0$).

What axioms are you starting from for exponentiation? One natural approach is to notice that in the reals, for $a>0$
$$a^x = e^{x\log a},$$
so if you have a definition for $e^x$ (for instance using the above power series) it is natural to define exponentiation of $a$ in any field using this formula as well. If $x = x_r + v$ is the decomposition of $x$ into its real and pure quaternionic parts, then by the formula you've listed above (and setting aside the question of checking that the power series of $e^x$ does indeed converge for all quaternions $x$, and does so to the formula you've listed):

$$a^x = e^{x_r\log a}\left(\cos [\|v\|\log a] + \frac{v}{\|v\|}\sin[\|v\|\log a]\right).$$

Comment: Notice also that the quaternions are a division ring, but not a field, since multiplication is not commutative; however the above formula for exponentiation is still well-defined since the real $\log a$ is in the center.